# Database request in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, pageload

In `Page_Load` I create dynamic controls (table with checkboxes). Number of checkboxes depends on some information that I retrieve from my database. I don't want to connect to the database on every postback. What is the best way to save needed variables? Maybe I need to store them in `HiddenField`?

Answer (score 0):

store them inside the viewstate, which is more or less storing in a hiddenField (as the viewstate itself gets persisted to a hiddenfield)

[viewstate @ msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Comment: Just curious.. If a control gets created once (even dynamically), wouldn't it be available in viewstate by default (without doing anything about it)? If so, I think what he is really doing is recreating the controls again and again, which should be stopped. My suggestion would be to just supress the control creation behind IsPostback condition and it should be alright..

Comment: the properties are stored inside the viewstate of the page, yes ... but you would need to recreate the control, to get the key (aka the control id) to access its properties. and, no it's a proper way to recreate the controls after each postback.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to get your variables values from **database** in this case. However, if you choose not to follow the recommendation, you still can store these values as **session state** variables if it is ok in your system...

If you run out of options you can consider using **ViewState** variables to store your variables.

---

Read about [State Variables](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/maintaining-state-in-aspnet-know-your-options/748)